# How to change the page height dynamically from the code in Stimul Report prints?

Tags: c#, printing, stimulsoft

I am using Stimul Report components in my Windows Form (C#.net), to print invoice in my program. As a result the printed papers would have vary height due to different count of goods. I am using 80mm papers, not standard A4/Letter size. The goods are passed as a `DataTable` named `dt` in my code.

```
report.RegData(dt);
int pageNewHeight = ((dt.Rows.Count)*4) + 10;
report.Pages[0].Height = pageNewHeight;

report.Print(false, printSet);
```

It still doesn't work and I get the *.rmt* file paper size. Any idea please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is solved;
We should specify the page height before compile, but after uploading the .mrt file.
So the order of the code would be:

```
        StiReport report = new StiReport();
        report.Load("c:/s80.mrt");

        report.RegData(dt);
        int pageNewHeight = (dt.Rows.Count * 4) + 10;
        report.Pages[0].Height = pageNewHeight;
        report.Compile();
```